# Can I use Get with EXTJS

Tags: jquery, extjs

I'm in the process of learning ExtJS after using JQuery for years.  I like the ease of use with JQuery but I'm having difficulty trying to do similar things with ExtJs.  Currently I'm trying to get a PHP page while passing it an argument.  In retrun I need to populate a select box with the data.  With JQuery the call would look something like this:

```
$.get("test.php?id=abc", function(data){
    $('#result').html(data);
});
```

Can I do something like this with ExtJS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to use [Ext.Ajax.request()](http://docs.sencha.com/core/manual/content/ajax.html) and write something like:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: "test.php?id=abc",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(response) {
        Ext.get("result").update(response.responseText);
    }
});
```