# Calling a PHP Class function with ExtJS?

Tags: php, extjs

Based on my previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704687/can-i-use-get-with-extjs) I'm trying to use ExtJS to call a function from a PHP class that lives in another area.  Is this even possible or should I create a new PHP and simply pass it args?  I'd prefer to use my existing code so I'm not duplicating it.

My current PHP Class handles my DB connection etc but I have no idea how or if I can instantiate the class and call a function using ExtJS.

```
<?php

class productInfo extends productInterface {

....

    function getProducts($code) {

        if (!$this->isConnected())
            $this->connect();

        $products = null;

        $query = "SELECT id, product FROM products Where id =  $code";

        $result = $this->dbConnection->exec_query($query);
        if ($result){
            while($row = $this->dbConnection->fetch_array($result)) {
                $products [$row['id']] = $row['product '];
            }
        }

        return $products ;
    }
}

?>
```

Client side code:

```
<select id="productFamily" onchange="getProducts()">
<option value="select">Select</option>
    ...
</select>
```

ExtJs

```
function getProducts(productFamily){

    var value = Ext.get("productFamily").dom.options[Ext.get("productFamily").dom.selectedIndex].value;

    Ext.Ajax.request({
            // How do I call getProducts(value) from ExtJS ???
    });
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Give us an example of what you are trying to achieve and what came up with so far.

Comment: I added my PHP code but I have no idea how to instantiate this class and call into my function via ExtJS

Comment: Let me rephrase it: why do you need to call this code from ExtJS? Why don't you make an ajax call to that service?

Comment: What do you mean by service...the class? This code needs to get called if a user makes a selection change on the client side.

Comment: The most common thing to do on those cases is to have a URL that will return the result of that query you are trying to execute in a JSON format, for example, and ExtJS will process that url as an ajax request. Try googling for that.

Comment: I guess that answers my question...it's not possible to call into a class with ExtJS correct?

Comment: Well... I don't wanna answer a question that I can't. What I can tell you is what I already did. Try that out and see if that solves your general problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

drgomesp's recommendation is definitely the easiest way to go.

However, there *is* a way to expose your server side API for use with ExtJS. If you really want to use your PHP functions via ExtJS, check out Ext Direct:

http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/extdirect